# Passing value to php script via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem to pass value to my php script via Ajax, there is my code :

I send value to ajax via a href link :

After scan directory i get links of my files on href :

```
<a href=""  onclick="getfilename('<?php echo $file; ?>');"><?php echo $file;  ?></a>
```

My js function to receive value :

```
 function getfilename(content) {

 alert(content); // i can see my value here

 $.ajax({ //not work

type: 'POST',
url: 'script.php',
data:{song: content},
async: false,
success: function(response) {
alert(response); //nothing
 });
}
```

My script.php

```
$album = $_POST['song'];
echo $album;
```

I dont understand why it does not work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: the code seems to be alright, my first guess would be to verify the url `script.php`.....are you sure the path is correct? It's in the same folder as your JS file?

Comment: use firebug to check response. And when you say "does not work", what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Both file is located in the same folder, does not wo

Comment: does not work, beacause Ajax not showing data received by php in success: function(response) {
alert(response); //nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<a href=""  onclick="getfilename('<?php echo $file; ?>');"><?php echo $file;  ?></a>
```

To this

```
<a href="#"  onclick="getfilename('<?php echo $file; ?>');"><?php echo $file;  ?></a>
```

Maybe your page is refreshing before the ajax data loads.

Comment: Happy to help. If you think this is the correct solution please mark it as your accepted answer. It allows others wanting to help people to see this post as "answered" so they can move on. If someone else's answer is more correct, select that one.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your js code your success callback is missing a "}" in the end of function.

```
// $file = 'teste';
<a href="#" onclick="getfilename('&lt;?php echo $file; ?>');"><?php echo $file?></a>

function getfilename(content) {
  alert(content);

  $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'script.php',
    data:{song: content},
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
        alert('Response: ' + response); //Alerts Result
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
// Script.php

<?php 
  echo $_POST['song']
?>
```

Comment: This is true it miss } :) but my problem came from my a href link, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When you use the link element it will automatically go to the location in the href after it executes the onclick event. Leaving it empty will reload the page.

I would recommend you to add a "return false;" as the last instruction of the onclick.

```
<a href="" onclick="getfilename('<?php echo $file; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $file?></a>
```

Hope this helps.